# How do I set the output audio device for a VBS SAPI speech script in Windows?

Tags: vbscript, sapi

How do I change the output audio device in a SAPI speech script?

The code below works great but I need to send the audio to a different audio device (specifically a virtual audio cable so I can mix it with Voicemeeter).  It will probably look something like 'CABLE-A Input (VB-Audio Cable A)'.  I Googled around but couldn't find anything useful on setting SAPI devices.

The existing VBS script, which runs from a Windows 10 command line, is below:

```
Dim speaks, speech
mm_now=Month(date)
mmm_now=MonthName(mm_now)
dd_now=day(date)
yyyy_now=Right(year(date), 2)
speaks = " . . " & mmm_now & " " & dd_now & " twenty" & yyyy_now & ampm
Set speech=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
speech.Speak speaks
```

How might I modify this script to send the audio to a different device?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: [SpVoice AudioOutput property (SAPI 5.3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723596(v=vs.85))

Comment: I'm really not familiar with SAPI and can barely get around in VBS... how would I set the AudioOutput property?

Comment: OK somehow I managed to figure it out. I'm adding a separate comment for the solution since I can't seem to post code in the reply.

Answer (score 2):

OK I found a solution, probably poorly written but it seems to work.  If anyone knows a more elegant solution feel free to reply.

```
(((all code above the line "sapi.Speak speaks")))

for i = 0 to speech.GetAudioOutputs.Count - 1
  s = speech.GetAudioOutputs.item(i).getdescription
  if (instr(s,"CABLE-B Input") > 0) then
     Set speech.AudioOutput = speech.GetAudioOutputs.item(i)
  End If
next

speech.Speak speaks
```